# Why is it allowed to use any email adress in "From: " header in PHP.Mail() function?

Tags: php, email

I appologize, if my questions sound naive, but I have no one to ask. I am new in PHP and right now I am playing with **PHP.mail() function**.

I am using XAMPP, PHP, SMTP server in our work just to see the functionality. 
In **C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini** I set

```
smtp_server=mail.heaven.com
auth_username=fairy
auth_password=nice
```

I created sendmail.php to send test mail to myself:

```
<?php
$to      = 'fairy@heaven.com';
$subject = 'greetings';
$message = 'if you read this, everything is fine';
$headers = 'From: devil@hell.com';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

I ran that and received email from `devil@hell.com`, so actually from me. I could not find out real sender from this message and my attempt to reply  failed... because `devil@hell.com` did not exist, of course.

And now comes, what confuses me. As far as I know, the first step is to provide the real login and the pass (auth_username, auth_password) to the SMTP server. The server knows I exist, it lets me in, so I can send email from my REAL account. 
I thought, that SMTP server takes automaticaly all necessary info from my account and wrap it into the email message, so the other people could reply, but obviously not.

I do not understand, why can I add misleading information so easily. It seems me, I can use my account to generate fake emails to molest my colleagues daily. I was not able to find out, who actually was the real sender.

Is this information stored anywhere? Is it possible for a client to see, who sent email or is it totally dependent on the `From: header` in PHP.mail() function?

Thanx for clarification

Comment: Email wasn't designed to be secure.  Here's [a cross-site Q&A](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/why-is-it-even-possible-to-forge-sender-header-in-e-mail) about the subject.  Various extensions to the core protocol exist, some more widely implemented than others.

Comment: SMTP server not necessarily means actual email. E.g. Amazon SMTP provides functionality to send SMTP, but not provides email address

Comment: That's not PHP's fault. That's the underlying mail system (sendmail, postfix...) that does according to the standards. When contacting a mail server (to send a mail) there is no verification the *sender* actually exists and is correct (that would be difficult to implement)

Comment: @ringø: so can I blackmail somebody every day and he would not be able to protect himself, because From header would be always different? Is this the philosophy how spam works?

Comment: When you send an email you say who it is coming from, the same way you do when you send a letter. That is how email works. You can read the RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321 if you want more info

Comment: Well, yes, you might spam someone with a different name every day. There is a trace however, the initial sender server IP address. To get trusted that server needs *usually* to comply with some rules (reverse DNS gives same domain as sender, some DNS fields added (eg for Google)...). And you don't want the server to be blacklisted..., so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the way `SMTP` protocol is made.

You're telling the recipient who you're supposed to be, and how it can answer you. There is no central repository of who controls a email domain, or an email user.

It can check by itself, by implementing security mechanism, such as what gmail is doing using DKIM. You can't impersonate a gmail email.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail for more information.

Comment: Well, you can definitely spoof a gmail email address, just not to another gmail user.

Comment: You can't send an email with a gmail "from" without using gmail smtp servers.

Comment: @blue112 You can if the recipients mail server is lax about checking where it _really_ came from.

Comment: @blue112 You most certainly can send it. It is just up to the recipients server if it accepts it or not, which is something very different to not being able to send it

Comment: ... and there was me thinking that lovely Dr. Bakare Tunde, who needed my help to transfer funds out of Nigeria, was legit with his gmail.com address :(

Comment: @blue112: your link points out what I was expecting to happen in my case. Anyway, there must be the tools to track down real email sender.